# MySQL Join across multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

My web application requires a list of all user groups, the group members, and a list of products that they have access to based on their group membership.

The web application supports multiple "sites"; a site being a unique identifier for those users, groups and products.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT u.id as user_id, u.username, ug.group_id, ug.group_name, u.firstname, u.surname, p.product_name, p.product_id, p.product_price, p.product_currency, p.is_public
    FROM user_groups ug
    LEFT JOIN user_group_users ugu ON ug.group_id = ugu.group_id
    RIGHT JOIN users u ON u.id  = ugu.user_id
    LEFT JOIN user_group_product ugp on ug.group_id = ugp.group_id
    LEFT JOIN product p on p.product_id = ugp.product_id
    WHERE u.site_id = 5
    ORDER BY ug.group_name desc, u.surname, u.firstname, u.username
```

This is working well, and I concatenate the results using PHP to deliver the data.

**QUESTION**: The `PRODUCTS` table also has an `is_public` flag, and I would like to include all products in the result set that ALSO have this set to 1 as well as return products that the user has group access to, but again, only for this site.

So, for clarity, I wish to return:

- All user records - no matter if they have group membership (ungrouped users will be displayed)
- All user records with associated group membership
- All groups
- All products - where a user is a member of the group
- All products - where the product is set to public - is_public = 1

All of the above must only be for the site in question.

**UPDATE 3**: Updated description of requirments

**UPDATE 2**: Tables structures:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `user_group_users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_group_users` (
  `user_group_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL default '0',
  `group_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL default '0',
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`user_group_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`,`group_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=54 ;

--
-- Table structure for table `user_groups`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_groups` (
  `group_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `site_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `group_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `is_default` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Users are automatically added to default groups at registration',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`group_id`),
  KEY `site_id` (`site_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

--
-- Table structure for table `user_group_product`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_group_product` (
  `user_group_product_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `group_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL default '0',
  `product_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL default '0',
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`user_group_product_id`),
  KEY `product_id` (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=124 ;

--
-- Table structure for table `product`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
  `product_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `payment_enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `credit_enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `product_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL default 'Default Product',
  `is_public` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '1',
  `product_price` decimal(10,2) default NULL,
  `product_currency` varchar(5) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`product_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;
```

Comment: Have you tried `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT` and `RIGHT` joins and add this condition to the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Can you include your table structures? Your question says, "a site being a unique identifier for those users, groups and products"; you are currently selecting by site on users, but not on groups or products.

Comment: @Mahmoud Gamal - Thanks for the suggestion, however I did not clearly state that I must return ALL users for the site, even if they have no group access, as these will have access to public products i.e. is_public=1. I have now added this to the original question.

Comment: Both users and user_groups have `site_id` on them - should these always be the same? If not, do you want to include users that do not have access to site 5 via their own `users` record, but do have access via their `user_groups` record?

Comment: @MarkBannister - Thanks for your comments. The site_id value is duplicated in both tables and identical. So I need all users, all groups, and all products that either the user has access to (via group membership), or the product is public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your requirements correctly, this should work:

```
SELECT u.id as user_id, u.username, ug.group_id, ug.group_name, u.firstname, u.surname, p.product_name, p.product_id, p.product_price, p.product_currency, p.is_public
FROM user_groups ug
JOIN user_group_users ugu ON ug.group_id = ugu.group_id
JOIN users u ON u.id  = ugu.user_id
JOIN user_group_product ugp on ug.group_id = ugp.group_id
JOIN product p on p.product_id = ugp.product_id
WHERE u.site_id = 5
UNION ALL
SELECT u.id user_id, u.username, NULL group_id, NULL group_name, u.firstname, u.surname, p.product_name, p.product_id, p.product_price, p.product_currency, p.is_public
FROM users
CROSS JOIN product p
WHERE p.is_public = 1
ORDER BY 4 desc, 6, 5, 2
```

- it should return all products that users on site 5 have group access to, together with all public products for all users.

Comment: Many thanks Mark. This structure looks ideal however the result set includes products from other sites. Somewhere the site_id is being ignored, probably in the UNION ALL SELECT.

Comment: @Ben: Do the products from other sites have NULL user groups and is_public=1? If so, they are included because you asked for all public products for all users?

Comment: @Ben: Please not that although you have made a number of references to products being "from other sites", **there is nothing in your data structure that makes a product specific to a site**. From what you have told us, only **users** are specific to a site.

Comment: @Ben: Do you have a lookup table that maps products to sites (so that a publicly-available product may be available to specific sites)?

Comment: Ah yes! I do apologise. Yes, indeed there is another set of tables that maps products to sites. I have added these joins to the lower SELECT under the UNION ALL and success!

Many thanks for the above SQL, as the UNION ALL is a much better way of addressing the problem with the two joins to the products.

All the best, Ben.